# Square vs Round Air-core Inductors for RF filters: When would you use one vs. the other?

Tags: rf, filter, inductor, passive-networks, passive-filter

The [Kyocera AS-series Square Core Inductors](https://www.kyocera-avx.com/products/inductors/rfmicrowave-inductors/as-series/) boast that *"the unique square cross section of the air core inductor **provides better performance**, and offers manufacturing advantages over toroidal coils."*  (Emphasis added. For this question, who cares about manufacturing adavantages, I mean obviously square doesn't roll around in the solder paste, but we want to know about RF behavior.)

Their round [AL-series](https://www.kyocera-avx.com/products/inductors/rfmicrowave-inductors/al-series) inductors do not mention their *roundness*, only to say that *"the air core inductors [are] better [than] solid core inductors..."* but this question is about square vs. round, for air-core only (not solid core).

**Question:**

How is it that square-wound air-core inductors are somehow *"provides better performance"*?  Better in what sense?

Comment: "*offers manufacturing advantages over toroidal coils*" Translation: cheaper to make. Better performance: Better cost performance :P

Comment: I'm just shooting from the hip. I've not studied it. But I can say a few obvious things. All other things equal and both constrained by a square region within which the circular cross-section must reside, then the square cross-section will have a lower Q and greater resistance (obviously) but also a larger inductance. I would also worry a little about excess radiation (another tiny source of loss) at the corners for the square case. I would hazard a guess, though, that *better performance* is in the eye of the beholder. Perhaps getting more inductance in the same space?

Comment: It's data sheet page 1 marketing BS.

Comment: These are surface mount inductors - round air core inductors won't lay flat on a PC board and have carriers with a flat surface.  The "square" allows the inductor wires themselves to form the flat surface that lies on the board, presumably giving a little more room for copper for a given surface mount size.  But I  mostly agree with Andy aka.